# Submitting a form from Image Maps

Tags: php, forms, imagemap

Im working on an assignment that requires the use of image maps. To keep this question short my example is that one image is displayed that shows various 'products'. I want to be able to present each products details when the user clicks on that corresponding area of the image. I know to use a single image within a form I can do:

`<input type="image" src="my/image.png" name="someName" value="Submit">`

However I'm not sure how this would work with an image map as I would be working with:

`<area class="className" shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,10">`

`<area class="" shape="rect" coords=""`
etc...

So in short my question would be can i submit a Form REQUEST using image maps or would i have to separate the above example into three separate images. 
Please see my example image in the link that is used as an image map

[image: Click here to see example image]

Comment: Use AJAX php for this call a function on hover of that part

Comment: I tried an approach where with my jQuery script i would invoke jQuery's .get() method however i couldn't receive that information from my php script. Any further info you can give ? @SunilPachlangia